# Why does $scriptBlock.GetPowershell().Invoke() fail to see my script's functions?

Tags: powershell

Take the following script:

```
function Do-Test
{
    # Do stuff here that relies on PS modules and variables loaded in my current session
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}

$scriptBlock = { Do-Test }

Write-Host "Invoking directly"
$scriptBlock.Invoke()

Write-Host "Invoking Via GetPowershell()"
$scriptBlock.GetPowershell().Invoke()
```

The latter causes an error stating it can't find the `Do-Test` function.  Can someone explain why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

This won't work because `GetPowerShell()` creates a new runspace where the `Do-Test` function is not defined.  You will need to define the function in the new runspace. What exactly are you trying to do?  You can do this:

```
$ps = [powershell]::create()
[void]$ps.AddScript(@'
    function Do-Test
    {
        # Do stuff here that relies on PS modules and variables loaded in my current session
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
        "Hello from $($MyInvocation.InvocationName)"
    }
    Do-Test
```

'@)
    $ps.Invoke()